# How to open HTML files not as templates in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I am using PyCharm and I use Jinja2 templates. In the project structure, I have marked the template directory as "Template Folder".

When I set "Python Template Languages" to Jinja2 then *all* my .html files are opened with the template editor, not only the ones in "Template Folder".

How to open the "Template Folder" files with the Jinja2 editor and all other HTML files with the HTML editor?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such possibility as of PyCharm 4.0. You're welcome to file a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/